# Curl command with option -d issue

Tags: bash, curl

Trying to send some data via API call (curl) but having issue with the format of the curl command:

```
serviceMsg="$(cat /tmp/response_time)"
perfData=$(/bin/echo "${serviceMsg}" | /bin/sed 's/,//g')

        StatusCode=0

curl -k -s -v -u user:password -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST 'https://localhost:5665/v1/actions/process-check-result?service=ExternalURL!ResponseTime' -d "{ \"exit_status\": $StatusCode, \"plugin_output\": \"${perfData}\", \"performance_data\": [ ${perfData} ]}"
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{
    "error": 400.0,
    "status": "Invalid request body: Error: lexical error: invalid character inside string.\n                                        { \"exit_status\": 0, \"plugin_ou\n                     (right here) ------^\n\n"
}
```

what I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't hand-code JSON: use `jq` to generate it for you:

```
perfData=$(sed 's/,//g' /tmp/response_time)

json=$(jq -n --arg sc "$StatusCode" --arg pd "$perfData" \
        '{exit_status: $sc, plugin_output: $pd, performance_data: [ $pd ]}')

url='https://localhost:5665/v1/actions/process-check-result?service=ExternalURL!ResponseTime'

curl -ksv -u user:password -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST -d "$json" "$url"
```

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks !